# Scrapy Selenium unable to make Request() callback

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

Scrapy and Selenium play nice if everything is in the same function `parse()` but because I need to add much more code inside parse function I want to split scraping part to separated function `parse_data()` and to use Request() but callback doesn't work at all.

```
class MySpider(Spider):
    name = "myspider"
    start_urls = ["http://example.com/Data.aspx",]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.driver.close()

    def parse(self, response):
        item = MyItem()
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        sel = Selector(response)

        buttons = len(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@class='buttonRowDetails']"))

        for x in range(buttons): 
            time.sleep(5)
            button = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//input[@class='buttonRowDetails']")[x]
            button.click()
            time.sleep(5)

            response = TextResponse(url=self.driver.current_url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
            print '\n\n\nHELLO FROM PARSE'

            yield Request(response.url, meta={'item': item}, callback=self.parse_data)

    def parse_data(self, response):

        item = response.meta['item']
        print '\n\nHELLO FROM PARSE_DATA'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing that you've got your request filtered because it goes to the same URL (there is a duplicate request filtering middleware turned on by default).

Use `dont_filter` argument to turn off the filtering:

```
yield Request(response.url, 
              meta={'item': item}, 
              callback=self.parse_data, 
              dont_filter=True)
```